# Как добавить метод в во второй FarmBuild во второй скрипт на другом объекте?

Tags: c#, unity3d, методы

Есть 2 скрипта
Первый (находится на пустом объекте):

```cs
public Vector2Int GridSize = new Vector2Int(10, 10);
private Build[,] grid;
private Build flyingBuilding;
private Camera mainCamera;



private void Awake()
{
    grid = new Build[GridSize.x, GridSize.y];

    mainCamera = Camera.main;
}
private void Start()
{

}
public void StartPlacingBuilding(Build buildingPrefab)
{
    if (flyingBuilding != null)
    {
        Destroy(flyingBuilding.gameObject);
    }

    flyingBuilding = Instantiate(buildingPrefab);
}

private void Update()
{
    if (flyingBuilding != null)
    {
        var groundPlane = new Plane(Vector3.up, Vector3.zero);
        Ray ray = mainCamera.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

        if (groundPlane.Raycast(ray, out float position))
        {
            Vector3 worldPosition = ray.GetPoint(position);

            int x = Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.x);
            int y = Mathf.RoundToInt(worldPosition.z);

            bool available = true;

            if (x < 0 || x > GridSize.x - flyingBuilding.Size.x) available = false;

            if (y < 0 || y > GridSize.y - flyingBuilding.Size.y) available = false;

            if (available && IsPlaceTaken(x,y)) available = false;


            flyingBuilding.transform.position = new Vector3(x, 0, y);
            flyingBuilding.SetTransparent(available);

            if (available && Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                
                PlaceFlyingBuilding(x, y);


            }
        }
    }
}

private bool IsPlaceTaken(int placeX, int placeY)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < flyingBuilding.Size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < flyingBuilding.Size.y; y++)
        {
            if (grid[placeX + x, placeY + y] != null)
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private void PlaceFlyingBuilding(int placeX, int placeY)
{
    for (int x = 0;x < flyingBuilding.Size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < flyingBuilding.Size.y; y++)
        {
            grid[placeX + x, placeY + y] = flyingBuilding;
        }

    }

    flyingBuilding.SetNormal();
    flyingBuilding = null;

}
```

Второй (на префабе здания):

```cs
public HouseMechanic houseMechanic;
public Renderer MainRenderer;
public Vector2Int Size = Vector2Int.one;

private void Start() {}
public void Update() {}
public void SetTransparent(bool available)
{
    if (available)
    {
        MainRenderer.material.color = Color.green;
    }
    else
    {
        MainRenderer.material.color = Color.red;
    }
}

public void SetNormal()
{
    MainRenderer.material.color = Color.white;
}

private void OnDrawGizmosSelected()
{
    for (int x = 0; x < Size.x; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < Size.y; y++)
        {
            if ((x + y) % 2 == 0) Gizmos.color = new Color(0.88f, 0f, 1f, 0.3f);
            else Gizmos.color = new Color(1f, 0.68f, 0f, 0.3f);
            Gizmos.DrawCube(transform.position + new Vector3(x, 0, y), new Vector3(1, .1f, 1));
        }
    }

    public void BuildFarm()
    {

        if (recourses1.GetComponent<PlayerResources>().money >= costFarmMoney)
        {



            if (recourses1.GetComponent<PlayerResources>().rock >= costFarmRock)
            {
                if (recourses1.GetComponent<PlayerResources>().wood >= costFarmWood)
                {


                    recourses1.GetComponent<PlayerResources>().money -= costFarmMoney;
                    recourses1.GetComponent<PlayerResources>().rock -= costFarmRock;
                    recourses1.GetComponent<PlayerResources>().wood -= costFarmWood;

                }

            }


        }
      

    }

}
```

Как вызвать метод `FarmBuild` в скрипте `BuildManager` чтобы  ресурсы списывались после постановки здания?

скрипт где хранятся ресурсы (тоже на пустом объекте):

```cs
public int money;
public int rock;
public int wood;

public TextMeshProUGUI textMoney;
public TextMeshProUGUI textRock;
public TextMeshProUGUI textWood;

public void Start()
{
    //UpdateText();
}

public void Update()
{
    UpdateText();
    //Debug.Log("income");
}

public void UpdateText()
{
    textMoney.text = "Монет: " + money.ToString();
    textRock.text = "Камня: " + rock.ToString();
    textWood.text = "Древесины: " + wood.ToString();
}
```